# How to make nodejs know about installed python

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

Whenever I run the nodejs msi file, it executes a powershell script, complains about not able to find the python and downloads a new version of python everytime. I have added python to my path and even made an environment variable pointing to the executable.

python, PYTHON, %PYTHON% all of these open the interpreter. What else do i need to do for the nodejs to detect the installed python?

node version = 18.12.1
npm version = 8.19.2

Answer (score 0):

You can check the python keyword in the cmd command and check whether the response failed.

Here's a link to how to do commands in python:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/nodejs/executing-shell-commands/

Comment: will this work in windows?

Comment: I think yes @tony